# Changing too many observables at the same time crashes the browser

Tags: knockout.js

I have 75 selectboxes. Each of them is databound to a variable

```
MyModel.selectbox_1 = ko.observable(1);
MyModel.selectbox_2= ko.observable(2);
MyModel.selectbox_3= ko.observable(3);
MyModel.selectbox_4= ko.observable(3);
...
MyModel.selectbox_75= ko.observable(0);
```

Each selectbox has just 4 options.

I want to be able to change the selectboxes according to a users answer of a question.
For example to reset all of them

```
var variable_name = "";
for (var i = 1; i < 76; i++) {
 variable_name = 'MyModel.selectbox_' + i;
 eval(variable_name)(0);
}
```

If i do this, the browser doesn't respond for some seconds, and then it works.

Is there a better way of changing many selectboxes simultaniously?

May be with webworkers?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you make a fiddle ?

Comment: how about making an [observable array](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html)? `eval` in this context is just scary.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MeTw7/3/

Comment: it works:-) It didn't work localy, because firebug was active. Sorry:-)

Comment: @Brad, i don't know if an observable array would be correct in this context. Observable array fires the changed event if something is added or deleted. I want to be notified by every change of the selected value. Do i misunderstand an observable array?

Comment: Then you might want a regular array, not an observable array. Either way, making 75 separate fields and using eval is definitely *not* the way to go, ever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never use `eval`:

You can easily avoid it in this case by changing this:

```
var variable_name = "";
for (var i = 1; i < 76; i++) {
    variable_name = 'MyModel.selectbox_' + i;
    eval(variable_name)(0);
}
```

To:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 76; i++) {
    MyModel['selectbox_' + i](0);
}
```

But you should really consider using an array for the selects:

```
var i,
    Plan_Model = {
        plan_spread_options: ko.observableArray(['0', '1', '2', '3', '4']),
        selects: []
    };

// init
for (i = 0; i < 75; i++) {
    Plan_Model.selects.push(ko.observable(0));
}

// apply bindings
ko.applyBindings(Plan_Model, $("#plan_bilgileri")[0]);

// update
for (i = 0; i < Plan_Model.selects.length; i++) {
    Plan_Model.selects[i](2);
}
```

See updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MeTw7/5/) (also look at the simplified html).